# How to disable remote connections to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, remote-control, database-security

Normally the answer to question is to set:

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I have this set in /etc/mongod.conf. Unfortunately I am still allowed access to this database remotely. I have restarted the Mongo service a couple times, to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea as to why my database is still accessible remotely?

I'm using MongoDB version 3.0.9

Comment: try `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` instead

Comment: I will add to my question that it is MongoDB version 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remoting in to mongod clients using bindIp = 127.0.0.1 is possible through an SSH tunnel because the shell session is seen as 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 should be sufficient. Restart MongoDB server after the changes are done.

References:

http://greenwireit.com/it-tech-support-articles/enable-remote-access-default-mongodb-installation/

https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-and-disabling-remote-access-to-a-mongodb-server/

Comment: For reference, this is the version I'm using: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you must specify the mongodb.conf file when loading your mongod instance. Like so:

mongod --fork ***--config /etc/mongodb.conf*** --logpath mongodblogs/mongodb.log --dbpath mongod

Answer (score 0):

This is best variant in security aspect:

```js
 su <NOTROOTUSER>
 mongod --dbpath data --bind_ip localhost
```

Create new user on you server then log in.
Root is not recommended for running mongo server.